# Lecture notes or video lectures on generalised symmetries of differential equations.

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetry

Currently, I am reading the chapter 5 from the *Application of Lie groups to differential equations* by *Peter J.  Olver*. Unfortunately, I find it difficult to follow. Could you please suggest some video lectures or lecture notes on the same. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: See this free Canvas course: https://www.canvas.net/browse/bth/courses/differential-equations

Answer (score 0):

Olver's book is a bit advanced for first learning Lie theory applied to differential equations; cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1758002/128568). Try Bluman & Anco's [*Symmetry and Integration Methods for Differential Equations*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6101&panel=book_details) (2002).

Also, see Schwalm's lecture notes: [*Lectures on Selected Topics in Mathematical Physics: Introduction to Lie Theory with Applications*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6667&panel=book_details) (2017), to be accompanied with online video lectures ([as he did for his book on elliptic function solutions to ODEs](https://youtu.be/DCXItCajCyo)).