# lectures on lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, compact-manifolds

I am reading the Lectures on lie groups by J.Adams. But it is hard to understand for me. How can I get a good consciousness of this book? Is there any suitable book that cover this book with same notations?
I am looking for a book with same!!! notation with adams book. but more simpler.  tnx

Comment: What do you already know?

Comment: I have B.Sc in mathematics. a little manifold. more analysis and algebra.

Comment: For suggestions see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194419/whats-a-good-place-to-learn-lie-groups), or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461029/getting-started-with-lie-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1), and many other questions about references for Lie groups.